# Counting occurrence using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, count

I am trying to count the occurrence of a certain type of value in a CSV file column-wise, So what the program will do is ignore the row if there is 0 and count the rest.

```
Program pseudocode -

Count each column
if the value is greater than 0 count
else ignore
continue till the  last row of each column
print Total count
```

One thing to keep in mind - there are about 5000 columns and 50 rows & second row is the header. Also, the first column is text format which we don't want to count. If you check the images I attached it will make everything clear.  I tried a few but none of them are working.

```
df = df.set_index('ID_REF')
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(((df.notnull()) & (df != 0)).sum()), index=['Final']))
```

Here is the csv file image version :

[image: data csv file]

Here is the output I am looking for :

[image: output]

Comment: "if the value is greater" - which value? The only 0 I see in your example is the index of the first column. Do you want to count non-zero elements in each column?

Comment: What is the output of your current code?

Comment: If any value of each column is greater than 0, Yes the non-zero elements, If you check the output it should be clear, The first column is showing 54 that means there is no 0 values, but the 2nd one is showing 53 that means there is one 0 value,  the third one is showing 52 that means two 0 values in that column,  that's the output i am trying to find. If you have any more confusion do ask please :)

Comment: @harvpan @harvpan 

`df = pd.read_csv('transposed.csv').reset_index()

# update headers
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].set_index("ID_REF")

df.loc["Final"] = (df != 0).sum()`

This is the output for this code : 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15aPCxTUJ0f3JJQdFk7SbtSNveG7_fuPV/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
df.ne(0).sum()
```

To sum up the number of non zero values column-wise.

If you want to stick it back into your original dataframe, rename the series to `total` so that the index will be called that, and use `append`:

```
df.append(df.ne(0).sum().rename('total'))
```

**Example**:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  1  0  1
1  1  0  1  1  0
2  0  0  0  1  1
3  1  1  1  0  0
4  1  1  0  0  0

>>> df.ne(0).sum()
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    2
dtype: int64

>>> df.append(df.ne(0).sum().rename('total'))
       0  1  2  3  4
0      0  0  1  0  1
1      1  0  1  1  0
2      0  0  0  1  1
3      1  1  1  0  0
4      1  1  0  0  0
total  3  2  3  2  2
```

Comment: I have to store it after every column and the final result will have to output in csv .

Comment: just use [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html): `df.append(df.ne(0).sum().rename('total')).to_csv('filename.csv')`

Comment: can you modify your code to count only the numeric or float values ? Not the alphanumeric ones? Thanks